# Busboy is not storing image in locally

Tags: javascript, node.js, busboy

I am using `Busboy` is store files in locally. below is my code:

```
apiRoutes.post('/upload' ,function(req, res){
  var fstream;
        req.pipe(req.busboy);
        req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename) {
            console.log("Uploading: " + filename);

            //Path where image will be uploaded
            fstream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/img/' + filename);
            file.pipe(fstream);
            fstream.on('close', function () {    
                console.log("Upload Finished of " + filename);              
                res.redirect('back');           
            });
        });

});
```

This code is working fine in plain separate project. But when I am using this middleware in my project then its showing an error:

```
_stream_readable.js:498
dest.end();

TypeError: Cannot read property 'end' of undefined
     at onend(_stream_readable.js:498:9)
     at _combinedTickCallback(node.js:370:9)
     at process._tickCallback(node.js:401:11)
```

I google it but didn't find any solution. Please have a look at this code and help me please.

Answer would be appreciated.

Thanks